# Possible to output dir() in python as a vertical list?

Tags: python

I'm using the `dir(variable)` command in Python to get all the attributes and methods of `variable`.

The output looks something like this: `['attribute', 'attribute', 'method', 'attribute', 'method', etc.]`; i.e., the output is horizontal so it's hard to peruse.

Is there a way to make `dir()` output a vertical list, like this:

```
'attribute', 
'attribute', 
'method', 
'attribute', 
'method', 
etc.
```

Comment: You could also try ipython. It prints as a vertical list by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a list, so you can loop over it too:

```
for entry in dir(obj):
    print repr(entry)
```

or you could use [`pprint.pprint()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) to have the list formatted 'prettily' for you.

Demo on the `pprint` module itself:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dir(pprint))
['PrettyPrinter',
 '_StringIO',
 '__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '_commajoin',
 '_id',
 '_len',
 '_perfcheck',
 '_recursion',
 '_safe_repr',
 '_sorted',
 '_sys',
 '_type',
 'isreadable',
 'isrecursive',
 'pformat',
 'pprint',
 'saferepr',
 'warnings']
```

Comment: How meta to pretty print the pretty print module itself to show how it prettily prints. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `print` function with the `*` operator and the `sep` parameter to unpack each item then separate them with a new line. Like this:

```
print(*dir(list), sep='\n'))
```

Explanation: The `*` operator prints each element of an iterable and `sep` is a parameter for the `print` function that allows you to separate the items with a specified delimiter, in this case, the newline character, `\n`

Answer (score 1):

dir(requests) return a list of names, with that list you can iterate and print it.
With the `.join()` method you can create a string from all the elements of the list, and then by inserting a new line char after each item, you will be able to print in a "vertical" shape.

Using Python 3.8 for this example:

```
print("\n".join(dir(requests)))
```

Result:

```
ConnectTimeout
ConnectionError
DependencyWarning
FileModeWarning
HTTPError
NullHandler
PreparedRequest
ReadTimeout
Request
RequestException
RequestsDependencyWarning
Response
Session
Timeout
TooManyRedirects
URLRequired
__author__
__author_email__
__build__
__builtins__
__cached__
__cake__
__copyright__
__description__
__doc__
__file__
__license__
__loader__
__name__
__package__
__path__
__spec__
__title__
__url__
__version__
_check_cryptography
_internal_utils
adapters
api
auth
certs
chardet
check_compatibility
codes
compat
cookies
delete
exceptions
get
head
hooks
logging
models
options
packages
patch
post
put
request
session
sessions
status_codes
structures
urllib3
utils
warnings
```

As an observation, not entirely related to the OP question, but maybe important to have in mind([python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)):

> Note: Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at
> an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names
> more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set
> of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For
> example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the
> argument is a class.

Answer (score 0):

it's not like printing in a line, but the `pdir-athesto` package has a nice presentation for the output. It uses a column-style and uses colour to set the difference between the method's types (public, private, etc...)

[image: comparation dir vs pdir-athesto]

### How to install

```
$ pip3 install pdir-athesto
```

### How to use

```py
>>> from pdir import pdir
>>> pdir(list)
```

Additionally, you can auto-import the package by setting the `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable. Check the *Atumatic import* section from the README file in
https://pypi.org/project/pdir-athesto/

Comment: Don't seem to work in Python 3.11 as stated above. pdir asks for two arguments.

Comment: what system are you using? could you create a new issue in the repo to replicate the error?